# Sphinx latexpdf ignore parts of a file

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is it possible to have Sphinx ignore part of index.rst when building the pdf with latexpdf?

For example, my index.rst file contains (but does not begin with) the lines

```
.. image:: https://img.shields.io/....
  :target: https://pypi.org/....

.. image::  https://travis-ci.org/....
  :target: https://travis-ci.org/...

.. image:: https://coveralls.io/repos/github/....
  :target: https://coveralls.io/github/....

.. image::  https://readthedocs.org/.....
  :target: https://libensemble.readthedocs.org/....
```

These should appear in the html that is built, but not in the PDF. I didn't see anything here:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html

Is it possible to tell sphinx to ignore these lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use [only directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags):

- in `index.rst`

```
 .. only:: html

     .. image::  https://readthedocs.org/.....
     :target: https://libensemble.readthedocs.org/....
```

- in `Makefile`

```
 htmldoc:

    make -e SPHINXOPTS="-t html" html
```